# manual mvc4 data annotation model validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

I need to validate viewmodel manually.But I am getting null result after calling validate method on ModelValidator object.

```
 var temp = validators.First().Validate(basicDetails);
```

Is there any work around to validate manually created viewmodel?

```
public static ModelStateDictionary ValidateDataLead(LeadViewModel newLead, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var basicDetails = new BasicDetailsViewModel();
        basicDetails.Name = new FullNameViewModel();
        var modelState = new ModelStateDictionary();

        var types = basicDetails.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in types)
        {
            var propertyMetaData = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForProperty(() => basicDetails, basicDetails.GetType(), property.Name);
            var validationProvider = ModelValidatorProviders.Providers[0];
            var validators = validationProvider.GetValidators(propertyMetaData, context);
        }


        return modelState;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what the context is here but is there a reason you can not use: TryValidateModel(basicDetails)?

Comment: thanks JTmon .Is there any way to generate modelState for viewmodel?

Comment: ModelState is not part of the model. It contains the errors found during the hydration of the model before being passed to the action method. If you want to have the framework validate the model for you, you need to use TryValidateModel which returns true or false.

Comment: TryValidateModel() is working fine.

Comment: is there any way to generate modelstate for viewModel?